# R select sequence of certain length

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to select sequences of length 3.

Consider the following binary sequence.

```
sq
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   0
7   0
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  0
13  0
14  0
15  1
16  1
17  0
18  1
19  1
20  1
21  1
```

What I would like first is to identify the sequence of length 3.

I tried to use:

```
new = sqd %>% group_by(sq) %>% mutate(sq_cum = cumsum(sq)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

But it sum all the number `1` in the sequence, not the *consecutive* `1`.

What I want is this vector `seq_of_three`.

```
   sq sq_cum seq_of_three
1   0      0            0
2   0      0            0
3   0      0            0
4   1      1            0
5   1      2            0
6   0      0            0
7   0      0            0
8   1      3            1
9   1      4            1
10  1      5            1
11  1      6            1
12  0      0            0
13  0      0            0
14  0      0            0
15  1      7            0
16  1      8            0
17  0      0            0
18  1      9            1
19  1     10            1
20  1     11            1
21  1     12            1
```

Once I get that, I would like to subset the 3 first sequences.

```
   sq sq_cum seq_of_three
8   1      3            1
9   1      4            1
10  1      5            1
18  1      9            1
19  1     10            1
20  1     11            1
```

data

```
structure(list(sq = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), sq_cum = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 0, 9, 10, 11, 12), seq_of_three = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @akrun, sorry I mean the sequence of 1s. I mean sequence of 1s of length 3. Does it make sense?

Comment: I see that rows 8, 9, 10, 11 are ones, but the only seq of three is 8, 9, 10. Row 11 is not included even though it is in the seq of rows 9, 10 11. That's okay---you want at least *non-overlapping* sequences. But do there need to be 0s in between? That is, if you had six 1s in a row, is that 2 sequences of 3, or just 1?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` to create a grouping variable and then create the sequence of three by checking the number of rows and the values of 'sq' to create the binary column, `filter` the rows having 'seq_of_three' as 1 and then `slice` the first 3 rows.  If needed, remove the 'grp' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
sqd %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(sq)) %>% 
  mutate(seq_of_three =  +(n() > 3 & all(sq == 1))) %>%
  filter(seq_of_three  == 1) %>%
  slice(1:3) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#     sq sq_cum seq_of_three
#  <dbl>  <dbl>        <int>
#1     1      3            1
#2     1      4            1
#3     1      5            1
#4     1      9            1
#5     1     10            1
#6     1     11            1
```

NOTE: It is not clear whether we need `seq_of_three` column created or not.  If not, then the steps can be further made compact

---

Another option with `slice`

```
sqd %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(sq)) %>%
   mutate(seq_of_three =  +(n() > 3 & all(sq == 1))) %>% 
   slice(head(row_number()[seq_of_three  == 1], 3)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

Comment: interesting, how then would you subset the 3 first episodes?

Comment: @giacomo Sorry, I was thinking about the intermediate output.  Now, you will get the subset expected output

Comment: I think that it is good to have `seq_of_tree` in order to double check the data

Answer (score 1):

A different `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 group_by(grp = with(rle(sq), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 mutate(grp_seq = seq_along(grp)) %>%
 filter(sq == 1 & grp_seq %in% 1:3 & length(grp) >= 3) 

  rowid    sq   grp grp_seq
  <int> <int> <int>   <int>
1     8     1     4       1
2     9     1     4       2
3    10     1     4       3
4    18     1     8       1
5    19     1     8       2
6    20     1     8       3
```

Here it, first, uses a `rleid()`-like function to create a grouping variable. Second, it creates a sequence along this grouping variable. Finally, it keeps the cases where "sq" == 1, the length of grouping variable is three or more and the sequence around the grouping variables has values from one to three.

Comment: I can't really understand the code, but it works well on my data. What's `rowid_to_column()` and `rle` doing?

Comment: The `rowid_to_column()` line is there just to show that it really keeps the rows you wanted. For the other lines, please see the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(ave(df1$sq, df1$sq, FUN = seq_along), df1$sq == 0, 0)
# [1]  0  0  0  1  2  0  0  3  4  5  6  0  0  0  7  8  0  9 10 11 12

with(rle(df1$sq), {
    rep(replace(rep(0, length(values)), lengths >= 3 & values == 1, 1), lengths)
})
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1

df1[with(rle(df1$sq), {
    temp = rep(replace(rep(0, length(values)),
                       lengths >= 3 & values == 1,
                       seq(sum(lengths >= 3 & values == 1))),
               lengths)
    ave(temp, temp, FUN = seq_along) <= 3 & temp > 0
}),]
#   sq sq_cum seq_of_three
#8   1      3            1
#9   1      4            1
#10  1      5            1
#18  1      9            1
#19  1     10            1
#20  1     11            1
```